# Package bryanmorgan:webshot fails the Meteor build 1.4.4.2

Tags: meteor

1. I am trying to generate PDF from server side in Meteor JS.
2. I added meteorhacks:ssr, meteorhacks:npm first, my build was successful

When I added ***bryanmorgan:webshot*** to meteor and ran meteor, below is the error that I am facing,

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.4_2\mt-os.windows.x86_
32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^

Error: Builder can not write without either data or a file path or a symlink pat
h: os/packages/packages.json
    at Builder.write (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:259:13)
    at Builder.writeToGeneratedFilename (C:\tools\isobuild\builder.js:390:10)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:1388:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\mete
or-tool\1.4.4_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\unde
rscore.js:79:11)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:1381:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\mete
or-tool\1.4.4_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\unde
rscore.js:79:11)
    at [object Object].saveToPath (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:1271:9)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:380:23
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at IsopackCache._loadLocalPackage (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:317:18
)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:251:16
    at Function.time (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:305:10)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:250:17
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at IsopackCache._ensurePackageLoaded (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:241
:20)
    at C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:77:14
    at C:\tools\packaging\package-map.js:57:7
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\mete
or-tool\1.4.4_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\unde
rscore.js:87:22)
    at [object Object]._.extend.eachPackage (C:\tools\packaging\package-map.js:4
9:7)
    at IsopackCache.buildLocalPackages (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack-cache.js:76:24
)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:841:25
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at ProjectContext._buildLocalPackages (C:\tools\project-context.js:840:18)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:283:9
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at ProjectContext._.extend._completeStagesThrough (C:\tools\project-context.
js:273:18)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:265:12
    at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:490:12)
    at ProjectContext._.extend.prepareProjectForBuild (C:\tools\project-context.
js:264:13)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:563:29
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14
)
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at bundleApp (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:562:31)
    at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:631:35)
    at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:890:28)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-app.js:417:12
```

My current packages are as below,

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

meteor-base@1.0.4             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.17                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.3.4   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.0.0    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.7.3              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

kadira:flow-router      # FlowRouter is a very simple router for Meteor
kadira:blaze-layout     # Layout manager for blaze (works well with FlowRouter)
less@2.7.9                    # Leaner CSS language


practicalmeteor:mocha             # A package for writing and running your meteor app and package tests with mocha
johanbrook:publication-collector  # Test a Meteor publication by collecting its output

twbs:bootstrap
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
accounts-password
aldeed:collection2
check
mizzao:user-status
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks
#dfischer:phantomjs
meteorhacks:ssr
meteorhacks:npm
npm-container
bryanmorgan:webshot
```

Comment: Why do you use meteor hacks:npm ? On it's github page it states: "Meteor 1.3 has the build in NPM support. So, in Meteor 1.3 this package won't add anything." What happens if you remove this package?

Comment: it works. But I want to generate PDF, so any help?

Comment: The package uses `require("webshot");` so what happens, if you remove bryanmorgan:webshot and instead use the nam package "webshot" ? https://github.com/BryanMorgan/webshot/blob/master/lib/webshot.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your packages list into a new fresh project and got several errors. So first I had to remove

```
meteor remove meteorhacks:npm
meteor remove npm-container
```

where the first one is deprecated and the second one not recognized.

After starting the app, I got the following error:

```
While loading bryanmorgan:webshot@1.0.0...:
   error: Command failed:
   /Users/jank87/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.4_2.cf7olq++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm
   rebuild --update-binary
   Phantom installation failed { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
   '/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/mt-1wya3ja/npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/location.js']
   errno: -13,
   code: 'EACCES',
   syscall: 'open',
   path:
   '/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/mt-1wya3ja/npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/location.js'
   } Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
   '/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/mt-1wya3ja/npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/location.js'
   at Error (native)
   at Object.fs.openSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:549:18)
   at Object.fs.writeFileSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:1156:15)
   at writeLocationFile
   (/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/mt-1wya3ja/npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/install.js:161:6)
   at Promise._successFn
   (/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/mt-1wya3ja/npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/install.js:142:5)
   at Promise._call
   (/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/mt-1wya3ja/npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/kew/kew.js:373:13)
   at Promise._withInput
   (/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/mt-1wya3ja/npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/kew/kew.js:333:25)
   at Promise.resolve
   (/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/mt-1wya3ja/npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/kew/kew.js:105:27)
   at resolver
   (/private/var/folders/q_/nyqwc8q55qx3c_153hvt8zy00000gn/T/mt-1wya3ja/npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/kew/kew.js:409:17)
   at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:82:15)
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.16 install: `node install.js`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Which clearly comes from the bryanmorgan:webshot package.

As I commented earlier, the bryanmorgan:webshot package uses the npm package webshot. So I removed bryanmorgan:webshot and added the npm package:

```
meteor remove bryanmorgan:webshot
meteor npm install --save webshot
```

Which made my meteor server restart successfully.

Now taking a look into bryanmorgan:webshot and trying to create our own webshot:

webshot.js

```
import _webshot from 'webshot';

webshot = function (url, filePath, options, callback) {
    var webshotAsync = Meteor.wrapAsync(_webshot);
    var callback = [].slice.apply(arguments).pop();

    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
        throw new Error("Missing callback function");
    }
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        return webshotAsync(url, callback);
    } else if (arguments.length === 3) {
        return webshotAsync(url, filePath, callback);
    }

    webshotAsync(url, filePath, options, callback);
};


webshot("http://google.com", "./tmp/google.png", function (err) {
    // screenshot saved to /tmp/google.png
    console.log(err);
});
```

Runs fine and creates a webshot as desired.